# Send a value to a base class from a child class and use it in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There are two problems, the first is that the value of select is pre-set, i.e. I change one input field and immediately select changes to other data (this is correct), but the value remains the same. (is displayed correctly - new data,
but keeps the previous one - old data)

The value that changes in child class must be sent to the base class and then used in the **formatAmountFromLimit** function, which is called and takes that value in the body of the lambda in base class

**Base class**

Fields:

```js
function LimitsFields (props) {
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState(props.limit.unit)


  return <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
   

      <Form.Group controlId='formGridLimitAmount' as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Limit Amount</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            type='text'
            value={ limitAmount }
            onChange={e => {
              setLimitAmount(formatAmountFromLimit(e.currentTarget.value,unit))
            }}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId='formGridUnit' as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Unit</Form.Label>
          <UnitsDropdown
              unit={unit}
              setUnit={setUnit}
              limitType={limitType}
              entityType={entity}
              siteGroup={siteGroup}
              riskType={riskType}
              isUpdate={isUpdate}/>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
  </Form >
}

export default LimitsFields
```

**child class where change value (unit)**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const UnitsDropdown = ({
                           unit,
                           setUnit,
                           limitType,
                           entityType,
                           riskType,
                           isUpdate,
                       }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {label: unit || 'Loading...', value: unit || ''}
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (limitType === '') {
            setItems([{label: 'All', value: ''}])
        }
        if (limitType && !isUpdate && entityType) {
            getUnits()
        }
        if (isUpdate) {
            getUnits()
        }
    }, [limitType, entityType])

    const getUnits = async () => {
        await fetch('api/units?limitType=' + limitType)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(body => {
                setItems(body.map((name) => ({label: name, value: name})))
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log('UnitsDropdown Error' + e)
            })
    }



    return (
        <select className="form-control" disabled={isUpdate && riskType !== 'LENDING'} value={unit}
                required={isUpdate && riskType !== 'LENDING'}

                onChange={e => {
                    setUnit(e.currentTarget.value)
                    handleUnitChange(e)
                }}>
            {items.map(({label, value}) => (
                <option key={value} value={value}>
                    {label}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    )
}
export default UnitsDropdown
```

**function formatAmountFromLimit in base(**Fields**) where to apply the new value**

```js
<Form.Group controlId='formGridLimitAmount' as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Limit Amount</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            type='text'
            value={ limitAmount }
            onChange={e => {
              setLimitAmount(formatAmountFromLimit(e.currentTarget.value,unit))
            }}/>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly all you want to do is send a value from Child component to parent component right?
This is done using lifting state up.

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components

You can either declare a state in the parent component and pass its setState function to the child component.
Or you can pass the
formatAmountFromLimit function to the child component and call it from the child component itself when the value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can do that, but if select changes, it has the previous value. 
I can't figure out how to fix it, maybe look at UnitsDropdown, maybe you'll understand why...

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the issue. Could you maybe reproduce the issue in a codesandbox? Also what does handleUnitChange do? where is it declared  in UnitsDropDown?

Comment: I would love to show this problem in codesandbox, but I can't do it. The function is dependent and I would have to write a lot. The point is that when I change some input field UnitsDropdown shows a list and it changes depending on what the user enters and here `unit` has the previous value. 
For example in an empty input field we write a number and UnitsDropdown changes, 
and function `formatAmountFromLimit` uses unit="Value1" shows Value1, then we write second number, unit="Value1" shows Value2, third number unit="Value2" shows Value3 (shows new, but sets old in function - need new)